# Check if an user name is used for any jobs/WF updates/Email alerts/Reports etc

Tags: reporting, workflow, jobs

I would like to know if there is any easy way to find all the references of Salesforce User account (say, User X). For example, Workflow field update can use User X, Reports running user can be User X, certain Batch jobs can be scheduled using User X, Workflow outbound messages can use User X, SOQL using User X in Apex Classes/Triggers

So, I want to find all the references of User X. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use Eclipse IDE for Force.com.  Your Force.com project needs to include all metadata, not just the default apex classes/visualforce pages/components/triggers/staticResources.  You do this at project setup using the wizard.

Then use the Eclipse search function to search for User X.

Note that you won't be able to locate references to items in personal folders (such as personal report folders)